# check_ajax_referer retuns -1

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fetch-api

I'm building a custom API endpoint for WordPress, and when trying to secure it with nonce I can't get `check_ajax_referer()` to return anything but -1.

I'm using fetch to call my API.

This is my JavaScript front:

```
var nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'); ?>';
...
fetch('https://sdfsdf.dk/wp-json/bookings/v1/book/', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {"Content-type": "application/json","X-WP-Nonce" : nonce},
    body: raw 
})
```

On my PHP backend I have this:

```
function post_draft_booking( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    check_ajax_referer('wp_rest');
    
    Do something... 
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'bookings/v1', '/book/', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'post_draft_booking',
        'permission_callback' => function () {
      return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
    }
  ) );
} );
```

When the JavaScript is run -1 is returned in the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: IIRC you don't really need to check the nonce, the REST API will do that automatically (you can check this by doing the same request without passing the X-WP-Nonce header, the REST API should reply back with a 403 Forbidden error).

Comment: That is true, thanks. But why does it say so in the documentatation?  https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces

Comment: That's for when you send requests to admin-ajax.php or some other WordPress area that's not the REST API. The REST API has this validation already built-in and so you don't need to use it there.

Comment: Just in case: when I said "you don't need to use it there" I meant nonce validation. You still are required to include a valid nonce either via headers (as you're doing already) or via the `wp_rest` parameter when sending a POST request.